# Postgres distinct query in two columns

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to write a postgres query. For every distinct combination of (career-id and uid) I should return the entire row which has max time.
This is the sample data

```
id  time    career_id   uid  content
1   100     10000        5     Abc
2   300      6           7     xyz
3   200     10000        5     wxv
4   150      6           7     hgr
```

Ans:

```
id  time    career_id   uid   content
2   300           6       7   xyz
3   200       10000       5   wxv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done using `distinct on ()` in Postgres

```
select distinct on (career_id, uid) *
from the_table
order by career_id, uid, "time" desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE's for this. Something like this should work:

```
WITH cte_max_value AS (
SELECT 
  career_id, 
  uid, 
  max("time") as max_time
FROM mytable
GROUP BY career_id, uid
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.* 
FROM mytable AS t
INNER JOIN cte_max_value AS cmv 
  ON t.uid = cmv.uid AND t.career_id = cmv.career_id AND t.time = cmv.max_time
```

The CTE gives you all the unique combinations of `career_id` and `uid` with the relevant maximum time, the inner join then joins the entire rows into this. I'm using if you get two rows with the same maximum time for the same combination of `career_id` and `uid` you will get two rows returned.
If you don't want that you will need to find a strategy to resolve this.

Edit: Also the proposed solution by a_hrose_with_name's solution is far nicer and unless you need some level of compatibility with other servers (sadly syntax varies) you should use that instead.

Comment: Those dreaded backticks are invalid in standard SQL and Postgres.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Also, I definitely prefer your solution which is far more elegant.